# How to know Remote IP Address in JSP

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-headers, remote-server

I have web application through which payment transactions will happen.

**The flow of the Application**

User will open my application and click the **pay** button. Now i will redirect the request to Payment Gateway provider (ICICI, EBS, PayPal etc). Now, the payment gateway provider pages will appear in my website. Now the payment process will go through, and Payment gateway provider will post their response to my application(to JSP page). After capture the response i will process the request.

**My requirement**

How can i know the ICICI, PayPal or EBS server ip address when they call my JSP. If i call `request.getRemoteAddr()` it will give the client IP address. I want to know the IP address of payment gateway server.

Provider is posting the data as **GET** instead of POST. Here i didnt mention my acutal payment gateway provider.

Comment: If the provider sends a GET directly to you, then you will see the provider's IP. If you see the client IP, the GET comes from the browser (maybe initiated by the provider, e.g. using Javascript or a redirect). How exactly does the provider do this? And why do you need the IP address?

Comment: To prevent website from hackers, we are planning to check the IP address. And in my scenario when they call, 'Referer' of request header is not available.

Comment: Ah, so you want to do some kind of security check? Doing this via the IP address is generally not a good idea, because it can be faked. Again, please expand your question to explain *why you need the IP address*.

Comment: for security checking i need IP address.

Comment: Again, please clarify your question: *How exactly does the sender send its response.?* At any rate, authentication based on IP address is not secure. Use another mechanism, preferably the one recommended by the provider (see vlad b.'s answer).

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can only know this without help from the payment provider if

- there are no proxies between you and the provider, and
- the provider sends a HTTP POST (or similar) directly to you

In that case `ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` should give you the provider's address.

If you get the client browser's address instead, then probably the provider does *not* send the POST directly to you, but instead instructs the client browser to send it (most likely using Javascript). In that case, there is no way for you to find out the address the provider was sending from.

---

At any rate, why do you need to know the payment provider's IP address? You redirect to the provider yourself, so you already have the address, don't you?

Maybe you could explain in more detail what the flow of data is between you, the client browser and the payment provider, and why you want to know the provider's IP address? Maybe then we can help better.

Comment: The provider is posting GET data, and it is visible to the end user. The hacker, who is expert, can easily hack the application because only few parameters are encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

For PayPal you can use IPN
https://www.paypal.com/ipn

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is PayPal's message service that
>   sends a notification when a transaction is affected. Once IPN is
>   integrated, sellers can automate their back office so they don’t have
>   to wait for payments to come in to trigger order fulfillment.

With IPN you get a POST/GET call to your IPN url from the PayPal servers. This means that the customer does not have to return to your website after paying and you do not have to validate the customer data - instead, the PayPal servers do a 3-way handshake: they send you the payment data, you send back a check, and they validate the check that the data you have is correct. In this case the server ip is the originating ip from the http call.

Other services will probably have something similar to this.